# google maps react front end API key storage

Tags: reactjs, mern, api-key, google-maps-react

I am building a full stack MERN (MongoDB Express React Nodejs) application.  I am using the NPM package [Google Maps React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) to display google maps on my website.  I am having difficulty coming up with a strategy to secure my front end google maps API key.

In order to fully understand my problem it may be helpful to review the Google Maps React component code below

```
import {Map, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';
 
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map google={this.props.google} >
 
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
 
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: (YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY_GOES_HERE)
})(MapContainer)
```

Possible Solutions

Solution A

1. Store key in my Mongo database
2. make GET request to database to obtain the google Maps API key
3. put API key data string in google maps component

Solution B

- note: I did some deep digging to the the Google Maps React Node module files.  I found .env and .env.example files with in the google maps react node module files.  The .env.example file says `GAPI_KEY=FILL_IN_YOUR_KEY_HERE`

1. store api key in google maps react node module files

Concerns with solution A

- Possible solution is not secure
- API key data can be accessed by user

Concerns with solution B

- the node modules are part of my `.gitignore` file and therefore the google maps API key will not be available when the app is deployed

Thank you for your thoughts and time.

PS I used create-react-app

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/google-maps-platform-best-practices-restricting-api-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various options to securely store an api key. If you are using CircleCi for continuous builds, you can create an [environment key](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/). Check your build solution for something similar.

There are also alternatives for encrypting files such as [git-secret](https://git-secret.io/). That way you could use an environment config file.

Bottom line do not store keys in code or in config files unless you have it encrypted.